# upload with ajax and php without iFrame or flash engine

Tags: php, ajax, file, upload, progress

I am trying to make an ajax upload function with progress bar, i was trying to simplify an example i found of the internet and i came to this function:

```
<form>
        <input type="file" id="file" /><label for="file"></label><label id="aaa"></label>
        <button id="sub">abc</button>
    </form>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function uploadFile(files) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            $("#aaa").empty().append(e.loaded + " - " + e.total);
        }

        xmlhttp.upload.onload = function(e) {
            $("#aaa").empty().append("finish");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("post", "post.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", files[0].fileName);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", files[0].fileSize);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xmlhttp.send(files[0]);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#file").change(function() {
            uploadFile(this.files);
        });

    });

    </script>
```

it is working well when i upload files near or under 800kb - 1MB and it's very fast but it bugs out when i try to upload bigger files. The progress bar shows that it's uploading but the onreadystatechange doesnt trigger and the file doesnt appear on the server.

The php which reply to this ajax is this:

```
<?php
// e.g. url:"page.php?upload=true" as handler property
//print_r($_SERVER);
if(
    // basic checks
    isset(
        $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'],
        $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'],
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']
    ) &&
    $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'multipart/form-data'
){
    // create the object and assign property
    /*$file = new stdClass;
    $file->name = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']);
    $file->size = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'];
    $file->content = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // if everything is ok, save the file somewhere
    if(file_put_contents('files/'.$file->name, $file->content))
        echo "OK";*/
        $file->name = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']);
        $input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$file = fopen('files/'.$file->name, 'wb');
stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
fclose($input);
fclose($file);
} else {
    // if there is an error this will be the output instead of "OK"
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the server variables:

- MAX_FILE_SIZE
- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- memory_limit

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

You may have some limitation in these variables.

Regards!

Comment: the funny part is, when i try to upload a JPG for example .. which has like 500 kb, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt, it just blocks and doesnt trigger the onreadystatechange

Comment: Examine the value of the variable $_file["your_upload_file"] ["error"], Does it contain any error code other than zero?. Do a var_dump($_FILE) to view the file information to be uploaded.

Comment: when i do var_dump($_FILES) it sais only array.. and if i try to use $_file["your_upload_file"] ["error"] it doesnt work since i dont upload on submit, i try upload onChange on input

Comment: I mean do a var_dump($_FILES) or print_r($_FILES) in your post.php file.

Comment: It seems as if it were not sending a file on the form. Maybe not working the parameter "enctype" with value "multipart/form-data"?. I would not know what else to try.